# Lotus Notes web form - textarea issue in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, textarea, lotus-notes

I have a lotus notes form that users access via the web, on this form is an area with textareas for the user to enter there details. Once the form has been submitted the value is stored in a notes text field as a string. I have replaced the carriage returns with `<br/>` so that when the form is viewed through the browser the text is formatted with the correct format. When the document is edited through the browser i replace the `<br>` with /r/n so that the textareas have the correct layout. The issue is that the in IE the first row of textareas the text on the first line is displayed and the other lines of text in the textarea are hidden, if you edit the text with a enter or add a character the text that is hidden appears. In Chrome and firefox the text displays correctly

I have some javascript that writes the table values to the textareas

```
//creates columns with fields and buttons
    for(var c=1; c < colCount; c++) {
    switch(c){
    case 1:
    el = document.getElementById("step" + f + "-1");
    if (readMode) {
        el.innerHTML=storeSteps.value;
    } else {
    var t=storeSteps.value.replace(/<br\s?\/?>/g,"\n");
    el.value= t;
    }
```

The issue only occurs on the first row of the table, the rest of table creates the textareas and adds the content with no issues. The only difference with the way the textareas are created on this form is that the first row are computed fields on the form and the rest of the form uses a javascript to add a new row of fields

```
            case 2:
            cell = row.insertCell(i);
            cell.className = "potential-col";
            el = document.createElement(elTagName);
            if (!readMode) {
                el.name = "potential" + tableCount + "-" + rowCount;
            }
            el.id =  "potential" + tableCount + "-" + rowCount;
            el.setAttribute("cols","25");
                el.setAttribute("rows","4");
            cell.appendChild(el);
            break;
```

where as the computed field on the form is created using the following code

```
    TableCount := "1";

@If(
    @IsDocBeingEdited;
    "<textarea rows=\"4\" cols=\"25\" name=\"step" +TableCount +  "-1\" id=\"step" +TableCount + "-1\" value=\"\"  onfocus=\"displayNextRow(" +TableCount + ")\" /></textarea>";
    "<span id=\"step" +TableCount + "-1\">&nbsp;</span>"
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer was to do with the styling of the textarea, had a css file which had a width: 100%. set a border style and change width to a px value and voila issue solved